# Set Lock Screen Wallpaper (Android)

Tags: android, wallpaper, homescreen

On Galaxy S4 when click on set wallpaper there is three options:
Home screen
Lock screen
Home screen and lock screen

For Home screen there is api WallpaperManager.setBitmap()

Is there any way to set wallpaper for lock screen?

Comment: There is in API 24. Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38684673/3311560