# Is there any Lock Screen WallPaper Manager class in android

Tags: android, screensaver

Like there is a WallpaperManager class in android. Is there is any class in android for getting Lock screen drawable ? So that i can set that Lock screen drawable as a  background image in my application's screen lock.

Comment: Screen saver?  In Android?  Do you mean DayDream?

Comment: Sorry i meant the wallpaper that appears at the time of lock screen on-off.

Comment: @simon - i just got this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653954/how-to-set-android-lock-screen-image
That says "lock screen image" is not part of the Android SDK.
So I guess I can not get that image. I was earlier searching as screen saver that's why was not able to get any clue.
But your comments made me revise my search and directed to the correct link.
Thanks for the Help.
Still if one have any clue or hack to do this, Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

As of API 24, `WallpaperManager` now has two new methods: `getWallpaperFile` and `getWallpaperId`. You can pass in `WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM` for the system wallpaper or `WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK` for lock screen wallpaper. But again, this is only supported in API 24.

[EDIT]

`setBitmap` can accept the new flags as well, so you can choose which wallpaper you'd like to set.